# Move files in bulk on AWS S3

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an S3 bucket that has a directory structure with input and output folders. The files are stored in the input directory using a tool that uses java API to communicate with S3, but in the case of moving the files from the input to the output directory we need to do it using other alternatives (even if it is a java class implemented by us).

What I need to know is if it is possible to bulk move files given a list of files to move, without having to be file by file calling the mv command in the unix s3 cli that seems to be very slow. I checked some information regarding bulk delete on S3 with java, but I need some more expertise opinion, if there's one.

I'm open to suggestions on languages to use that can have a API that serves my purpose.

PS: the question regarding the list of files to move is critical because the criteria to get those files is not possible to be implemented using the usual include/exclude that we have available in the unix s3 cli

Thanks in advance

*********** EDIT *********

Just found out the boto3 API that was very simple to set up. Just adding this info and tags to the subject in order to have more insights on this. Tks

Answer (score 2):

There is no "move" command in Amazon S3. Instead, the objects would need to be **copied**, and then the source file **deleted**. This is what the AWS CLI actually does when doing `aws s3 mv`.

The great thing about the AWS CLI is that it **issues copy commands in parallel**, which greatly reduces the time to move a large number of objects. The fact is that the Amazon S3 CopyObject API call only accepts one object at a time. Hence, the need to issue such commands in parallel to move them faster.

An alternative is to use [S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/batch-ops-basics.html). You can use [Put object copy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/batch-ops-copy-object.html):

> The Put object copy operation **copies each object specified in the manifest**. You can copy objects to a different bucket in the same AWS Region or to a bucket in a different Region. S3 Batch Operations supports most options available through Amazon S3 for copying objects. These options include setting object metadata, setting permissions, and changing an object's storage class.

The list of objects to copy can be specified in a CSV file. You would then need to **delete** the objects after the copy, which can be done via `aws cli delete-objects` and a list of objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to call the aws cli on several files in parallel, you can use parallel on linux:

```
find . -name *.jpg | parallel aws s3 mv s3://bucketA/{} s3://bucketB/
```

You'll need to install it though. For example:

```
sudo apt install parallel
```

or

```
sudo yum install parallel
```